# nodejs(express) with socketio

Tags: node.js, socket.io

In my application  I am using socketio and nodejs. I am trying to implement  simple authentication. If user is authorized I have to redirect to my application otherwise I have to redirect to same page. the sample code I implemented is

```
<script>
     $(function(){    
        $('#join').click( function() {   
            var uname = $('#uname').val();
            alert(uname);
            socket.emit('news', uname);                             
            var pwd = $('#pwd').val();    
            socket.emit('pass', pwd);
        });
        });
</script>
```

The server code is ..

```
app.get('/', function(req, res){
      if(auth)
      {
          res.sendfile(__dirname + '/home.html');
      }
      else
      {
      res.send("hello user");
      }
});
io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket){   
      var uname;
      var pwd;    
    socket.on('news', function(data){       
    uname=data;
    console.log("the information i got is" + uname);
    });
    socket.on('pass', function(data){
    pwd=data;
    console.log("the information i got is" + pwd);      
    if ( uname==123 && pwd ==321)
    {
    auth=true;
    console.log("AUTHENTICATED USER");
    }
    });
    socket.on('disconnect', function(data){          
    });    
});
```

on console i am getting this

```
the information i got is123
the information i got is321
AUTHENTICATED USER
```

but the problem i am facing is if the user authorized it is not redirecting to another page

Comment: a problem i am facing is that i cannot read code that is not formatted and appears to lack a coding style

Comment: sorry for the problem.... on client side when ever client click on button i am storing username and password. on the server side when ever he open the socket i am taking the values from socket and checking the values if those are valid it should redirect to app using that app.get().... hope i explained the problem clearly...

Answer (score 1):

Try sending url to client and let the client browser handle the redirection...

How about this?

Client:

```
 $(function(){    
        $('#join').click( function() {   
            var uname = $('#uname').val();
            alert(uname);
            socket.emit('news', uname);                             
            var pwd = $('#pwd').val();    
            socket.emit('pass', pwd);
            socket.on('url', function (data) {
            window.location.href=data;    
  });
        });
        });
```

Server :

```
app.get('/', function(req, res){
      if(auth)
      {
          socket.emit('url', { msg: 'homePage' });  
      }
      else
      {
             socket.emit('url', { msg: 'hiPage' }); 
      }
});
```

Note:This is just a sample code,not executable one.